# binding dropdownlist in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

i have a Class called "Services" in the App_code folder that contain Method like this:

```
public static ???? GetAllCustomers()
{
    string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectToDB"].ConnectionString;

    using (SqlConnection connection= new SqlConnection(conn))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "select C_ID,L_ID,C_Name from Customer";
            cmd.Connection = connection;
            connection.Open();
            ????
            ????
        }
    }
    return  ???;
```

what should i use in the "????" as return type...because i want to bind dropdownbox.datasource to ???? and use the datavaluefield and datatextfield..
so should i make the method return datatable class or something else..
i hope i made my question clear..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return a System.Data.DataTable and use column names for datatextfield and datavaluefield.

Comment: can you please me explain how to deal with dataTable calss,i mean how my method will look like if i used DataTable, how i fill the Datatable with the results from the sqlcommand.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to write it with so much specificity (i.e., it's tailored to one specific dropdown, not abstracted to the point that it can be used by any other dropdown), then instead of a function, make it a sub (void? -- no return type in any case).  There's only two addtional steps to add then -- set the dropdown's datasource, and then call databind.

So then, you'd just call the sub each time you wanted to populate the dropdown.

If you want to abstract it a little more, so that it takes parameters for commandtext, or what have you, then a function would be a good idea.  In that case, datatable would be a good return type.